# What are some ways to protect admob account from getting suspended because of others making fake clicks?

Tags: admob, adsense

It could be off-topic but please it would be very helpful to all of us who are getting fake clicks from unknown sources just to get our admob account suspended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## For iOS

You should count how many times a user has clicked on your ad, using the delegate methods stated [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/ios/ad-events). You can also use `touchesBegan`.

Each time you detect the user clicks an ad, increment a value in `NSUserDefaults` or something. And maybe each week or month, you reset the value to 0. This way you can count how many clicks you get every week/month.

If a user clicks the ad, say, more than 5 times a week, you should stop showing the ad. How? Just don't send the `GADRequest`! You can also present a `UIAlertController` to tell the user.

## For Android

You should count how many times a user has clicked on your ad, using the event listener mentioned [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/ad-events).

Each time you detect the user clicks an ad, increment a value in `SharedPreferences` or something. And maybe each week or month, you reset the value to 0. This way you can count how many clicks you get every week/month.

If a user clicks the ad, say, more than 5 times a week, you should stop showing the ad. How? Just don't send the `AdRequest`! You can also show a `Toast` to tell the user.

Comment: Maybe he used a lot of devices, like 3 and made a spam attack and it was too late for that move ?, is there a way to notify google to stop the ads or removing the ad is the solution ?

Comment: Similar happened to me, got 69 clicks in a day and is it too late? @Abo Hani, What happened to your AdMob account?

Comment: It's still on, i made a script that handles the clicks and monitores it, even its going to be spamming clicks, it bans the user (save a unique id on an online mysql database). This's the best way.

Comment: can you share the script or how you did it ?